# French (?) animated 2d movie where a man follows a woman through various historical and future times

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I’m really desperate to find the name of the 30-40 min animated 2d film I’ve watched in my childhood. I remember the general plot and some scenes in the movie.

The story revolves around a man and the woman he loves as he follows her through different eras, from prehistoric times, to medieval, to current time and then to a futuristic setting. For some reason he seems to have the worst of luck, and either he gets murdered or she does, which switches the setting, I don’t really remember. In the end they somehow reunite and there’s a scene where they turn into birds and fly away.

Some scenes I remember is the lover being tortured while the man being forced to watch and some kid getting shot by a soldier over clean water in the futuristic settings part of the movie.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were a child, so approximately what year did you watch this?